# My MySQL connect code is not working in my html document

Tags: php, html, mysql

SO I am trying to connect to my MySQL database using php in my html document. When I upload it to the web it does not seem to work! Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass");
    mysql_selectdb("DB",$con);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    $mydata = mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens? do you get any error?

Comment: sigh... `mysql_*`......

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: localhost would be for your local machine

Comment: I see this question a lot. Please read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: localhost is your local machine | it is `mysql_select_db` instead of `mysql_selectdb`

Comment: My page appears blank @Xatenev

Comment: It's blank because you're not querying anything. Well, you are in a way, but you're not fetching anything from it/not echoing, just selecting from table.

Comment: I am I just have not displayed this code

Comment: Plus, as already stated, it's `mysql_select_db` and not `mysql_selectdb` - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Like i said, you have an error in your syntax which should stop PHP from doing anything: `mysql_select_db` | If your server is just for test purposes, you might display errors on your live server so you see what is going wrong :).

Comment: you should not use mysql_* you should either use PDO or MySQLi... see my post here for a more appropriate way to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410358/mysql-isnt-adding-info-to-my-database/25410388#25410388

Comment: @Xatenev you should post your comment as an answer, it'll get you some extra rep :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell How do I use your example for displaying data and then linking it to a more detailed page?

Comment: @bob my example is for how to correctly use a query and not use mysql_*... not for fixing your entire problem but rather just helping with sql injection and not using deprecated stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try uploading it as connection.php rather than connection.html

I hope this helps!